# I lvextend-ed the /, but there is still only 50Gbytes

Tags: centos, filesystems, partition, lvm

I have `pv`ed, `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb`, and I `vgextend`ed the `/dev/sdb` to the default VolGroup, and `lvextend`ed the `/`.

now the `lsblk` shows this:

```
[root@store01 ~]# lsblk
NAME                        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                           8:0    0 238.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1                        8:1    0   500M  0 part /boot
└─sda2                        8:2    0   238G  0 part 
  ├─VolGroup-lv_root (dm-0) 253:0    0  1010G  0 lvm  /
  ├─VolGroup-lv_swap (dm-1) 253:1    0  23.9G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─VolGroup-lv_home (dm-2) 253:2    0   100G  0 lvm  /home
sdb                           8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk 
└─VolGroup-lv_root (dm-0)   253:0    0  1010G  0 lvm  /
```

but when I put data into the `/`, the `/` get full:

there shows:

```
[root@store01 ~]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
                       50G   49G     0 100% /
tmpfs                  32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             477M   55M  397M  13% /boot
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home
                      162G   60M  154G   1% /home
```

---

now the vgs is this:

```
[root@store01 ~]# vgs
  VG       #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize VFree 
  VolGroup   2   3   0 wz--n- 1.14t 35.65g
```

---

**EDIT**

at first the / only have 50G, after the bellow commands:

```
pvcreate  /dev/sdb
vgextend VolGroup /dev/sdb
lvextend -L +950G /dev/VolGroup/lv_root
```

`lsblk` shows the upper print.1010G

Comment: `lvextend` enlarges the file system's *container*. Did you follow this by extending the *filesystem*?

Comment: Can you add the command `lvextend ` you use. Also also result of execution of  `vgs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to extend `lv_root` as a LV

```
lvextend --size +500G lv_root
```

then extend / as a filesystem, this depends on filesystem type

```
 resize2fs /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root  ## ext3/ext4
 xfs_growfs / ## xfs
```

note that I would advise you to put data on a separate file system, 50 G is more that enough for system, you should create a new FS ( `/data` `/MY_APP` whatever )

Comment: the `resize2fs /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root` will affect the `/`'s data?